# Which model and embedding to use for portuguese chat with docs

Tags: nlp

I would like to have a model to read all my personal documents, meeting notes and things like that, all text based, and then be able to ask questions like: what was decided about the feature x? what was proposed about y? I have tried some examples that I have seen online and they seem to do what I want. The thing is my documents are not in english. I tried some models like maritaca-ai/sabia-7b, llama-2, mistral and some embeddings like sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2.

The results are not good at all. Is it the model? Or the embedding type I am using? Can somebody suggest some resource for me to learn more about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @KellyGoedert, welcome to the site. I don't think your question can be answered with the information you provided. You should be able to diagnose if the embeddings are the problem by evaluating how good the found matches are. If the matches are good, then the problem is probably in the LLM. If the matches are bad, then there is probably a problem with the embeddings or the chunking strategy.